# How do i add a transparent background when search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My goal is to simply add a transparent background to the body of HTML when someone is searching on the input text field

Before searching
[image]

Once search[image]

Code

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Testing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <form novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return false;" class="searchbox sbx-amazon" style="margin-left: 20%" id="search-realtime">
        <div role="search" class="sbx-amazon__wrapper">
          <input type="search" id="search_input" name="search" placeholder="Search your product.." autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-amazon__input">
          <button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." class="sbx-amazon__submit">
            <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-11"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
          <button type="reset" title="Clear the search query." class="sbx-amazon__reset">
            <svg role="img" aria-label="Reset">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-clear-2"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


   </div>

</body>
```

On the search input later on, type in `"I will"` to see the result
You can check jsfiddle for full code https://jsfiddle.net/Ldpqhkam/2/

Comment: Set `opacity:` to anything less than 1.

Comment: you could give it an overlay. hide it and show it based on the value in the input text box. https://plnkr.co/edit/M4DryMbEk2QwUvFVTtAk?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `div` element somewhere within the `body` (preferably at the bottom), like so:

```
<div id="search-overlay"></div>
```

and give it this CSS:

```
#search-overlay { position:fixed; top:52px; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background:#000; opacity:.5; display:none; }
```

Then you toggle the `display` property of this overlay `div` by hooking into the appropriate events of the autocomplete, namely `autocomplete:shown` and `autocomplete:closed`

See working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ldpqhkam/5/

Comment: Thanks it does help but seems like it doesn't cover the entire page.

Comment: and I placed the code at the bottom of the page, the `div`

Comment: Do i need to change `bottom` to something?

Comment: try setting position:fixed; instead of position:absolute;

Comment: Thanks, but now there is another problem, whenever I scroll down, the transparent background will follow the scroll.

Comment: it is good in the beginning but when I scroll down, that transparent background will follow the movement of my scrolling. So technically the background is still not covering the entire body.

Comment: just set top to 0 then.  Then it covers the entire body but also the navbar.  If you dont want that then the navbar will also need absolute positioning and a z-index greater than the search-overlay

Comment: I don't understand the z-index greater than the search-overlay. How the code will look like?